# Pass partial list of arguments to do.call()

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that tests a series of hyperparameters for a GBM model. I only want three of the arguments to vary in the GBM call. The rest I want to be static. `do.call` seems to be the answer in that it takes a list of arguments and passes them into a function. However, I can't tell if there's a way to 'fix' some of the arguments that I never want to change.

```
parms <- list(
'interaction.depth'=1:5,
'n.trees'=c(500,1000,2000),
'shrinkage'=c(0.01, 0.005, 0.001))

res <-expand.grid(parms)

> head(res)
  interaction.depth n.trees shrinkage
1               1    500      0.01
2               2    500      0.01
3               3    500      0.01
4               4    500      0.01
5               5    500      0.01
6               1   1000      0.01
```

I then want to pass each row of my expanded grid into the GBM function as a list of parameters while 'fixing' the other parameters in place.  Something like:

```
#pseudo-codeish
apply(res, 1, function (row) {do.call("gbm", row)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do.call` requires a list for its second argument.   You can combine lists with `c`.
The following expression creates a list with elements `a`, `b`, and the named columns of `res`, using the first row for the data:

```
c(list(a=1, b=2), as.list(res[1,]))
```

The `apply` expression you want looks something like this:

```
apply(res, 1, function(row) do.call('gbm', c(list(a=1, b=2), as.list(row))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `m*ply` functions from the `plyr` package. To return a list of `gbm` models, do:

```
gbm.list <- mlply(res, gbm, formula = Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6, data = data)
```

where `formula = Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6` and `data = data` are examples of fixed parameters.